# How to avoid If Else statements in CG Shader Model 3 code?

Tags: algorithm, opengl, glsl, shader, hlsl

Help my code is compiling 12000 maths instructions! Suppose i have 20 small algorithms, each of which has 6 maths instructions + / - * etc. they are placed into 2 groups, A and B, of 10 algorithms per group, in a function that can combine any 2 algorithms from A and B... the result is only 12 instructions. but the graphics shader returns 10*10 combinations of 12 instructions, i.e. it compiles all 1200 different possibilies of algorithm. and if i add another selector C it makes 18000 instructions. because SM3 doesnt have dynamic branching it unrolls all loops of code into all possibilities.

```
        half algorithmA ( half s, float x)
        {
                if(s<=0) {return sin(x*2.2);}      
                else if(s==1){return tri(x);}
                else if(s==2){return rn(x);}
                else if(s==3){half v1= tri(x); return v1*v1*v1;}
                else if(s==4){return (abs(sin(x)))*2-1;} 
                else if(s==5){return lfo(x);}
                else if(s==6){return slfo(x);}
                //else if(s==7){return sin(x*2.2*sin(x*.3));} 
                //else if(s>=6){return fmod(abs(x),2)-1;} 
        }
```

So , selecting the algorithms by ELSE IF algo number == selector number, seems inefficient and crashes the graphics card/shader more easily... so i want to have just a selector that works like this:

algorithm no1 * (selector number XOR 1) + algorithm no2 * (selector number XOR 2)... etc up to 10...

the idea is that all the algorithms will be multiplied by 0 unless they are equal to the selector, and i  will have 100 compiled instructions of code instead of 1800, and 4 selector, is 24000 instructions!!! it's just a different form of selector that will compile better in CG shader.

QUestions: which logical maths operation should i use in HLSL/CG language instead of XOR, so that all options not equals to "selector number" multiply by 0, and option equals to selector multiplies by 1?

will it be faster that If-Else paragraphs?

in C code you could write an array of functions for the same task, and run a selector from the array.

Comment: Uhm, Shader Model 3.0 does have dynamic branching that was its biggest feature in my opinion. Are you sure you are not talking about Shader Model 2.0?

Comment: Perhaps SM3 has very limited branching, because if i write combinations of if-else instructions, i soon reach 1024 fragment instructions, which is sm3's limit, i can specify a higher instruction limit, it soon crashes. why does it overloads SM3 just to have if else instructions, if it has branching?

Comment: Yes, that is the case. Branches in Shader Model 3.0 can only have a depth of 24 instructions at maximum. Shader Model 4.0 removed this restriction. This [page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb219848(v=vs.85).aspx) will give you an idea of the cost of various operations, but keep in mind the bulk of the instructions in all of these branches is defined by the evaluating the return statement. Consider splitting this up into a couple of separate dynamic flow control if/else/endif blocks.

Comment: Thankyou. The Flow Control page is written very technically, i wish to write the best possibel SM3 shader where the user select 100 combinations of special forms, what is the most proper way to enounciate the selection code? In noob coder terms, what is best practice to program the gpu to make 100 selections?

Comment: Because i could use multiply by zero/one to select options, it would be possible?

Comment: If write a long line of maths with 100 arithmetic operations, of which 90 are pre-emptively multiplied by 0, it is a cool way of avoiding if else to have 1000 instructions compiled, how should i do it?

Comment: How many combinations of algorithms do you have?  It might be worth generating a shader for each one (programmatically), rather than putting all of that logic into a single shader.

Comment: Hi i have a multicompile option for same shaders, i have to do 7 * 5 * 2 *4 for the ideal shader that i wish to do, it would be amazing. that's 500+ combinations. it's a generative texture shader that can generate many textures.

Comment: 500 is not so bad.  Crysis had 85,000, I think :).

Comment: Using a lot of if/then/else statements is surely not the ideal solution, you create either a lot of code branching (poor parallelism) or all conditions will be evaluated (poor performance). If you are stuck with SM3, using conditional compilation to rebuild shader on the fly is your best option. If you can have access to SM5 instead, Shader Linkage and late binding would be pretty nice option for your use case.